# Error message ".innerHTML is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fill the date automatically in a table header, but all I get is

> ".innerHTML is not a function"

I've looked everywhere, and tried put my code at the top and bottom of the page, but nothing works. Help, please!

```
window.onload = function() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = currentTime.getDate();
  var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
  document.getElementById("dated").innerHTML(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
};
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is not a function; it's a string property that you can get/set.

Comment: @AtesGoral is right. Try setting the `innerHTML` like so `document.getElementById("dated").innerHTML = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;`

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Well, as the error says, `innerHTML` is not a function.

You can **assign a value to the property**, though:

```
document.getElementById("dated").innerHTML = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```

For more infos, **have a look at [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**.

Answer (score 28):

innerHTML is a property... thus you need to use = not ()... it's not jQuery.

```
document.getElementById("dated").innerHTML = "blah"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById("dated").innerHTML = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```