# How to overwrite text in <p> tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to *replace* the content of a `<p> tag` only with Vanilla JavaScript. I have something like

```
<div
    className='container'>
    <p
        className='element' id='replace-me'></p>
</div>
```

And then I have a function like this

```
setInterval(function () {
    ...
    document.getElementById('replace-me').innerText(someVar)

}, 1000);
```

That gives me the error:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...).innerText is not a function

Why is that?

Comment: It's not a function. You need to use it like this: `document.getElementById('replace-me').innerText = someVar;`

Comment: Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951999/error-message-innerhtml-is-not-a-function/37952034)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That's because [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) is an attribute so you should do :

```
document.getElementById('replace-me').innerText = someVar
```

instead

Comment: Oh dear... I didnt know that!

Comment: @Stophface that's why stackoverflow exists ;)

Answer (score 5):

Using JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('replace-me').innerText = 'Anything you want'
```

You can also use Jquery

```
$('#replace-me').html('Anything you want')
```

Comment: The OP asked a question that is in plain JS, not in jQuery.

Comment: I dont wanna use jQuery. I thing using jQuery for a simple selector is a little bit too much :)

Comment: I find OP questions can frequently enrich the learning of those of us who love to learn. For example, while @Lucas response #1 will satisfy, it does not allow the ability to add, for example, an a tag with classes. However, because he took the time to add the Jquery method, I was successful in replacing not only the text, but the entire HTML string (code including a tags and classes) to make the replace function more robust. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `jonatjano`'s answer, I'd like to add an alternative.

Just an alternative to `innerText` is `innerHTML` -

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
```

innerText retrieves and sets the content of the tag as plain text, whereas innerHTML retrieves and sets the same content but in HTML format.

Answer (score 2):

Try with querySelector ([Javascript querySelector vs. getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848289/javascript-queryselector-vs-getelementbyid))

```
paragraph = document.querySelector("#replace-me");
paragraph.innerText = "Your HTML Code";
```

If it still does not work, check that the element you want is selected.

[JavaScript: querySelector Null vs querySelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987071/javascript-queryselector-null-vs-queryselector)

Comment: `paragraph.innerHTML = "Your HTML Code" ` or `paragraph.innerText = "Your PlainText" `